# Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 552 5.7.0 DATA header size exceeds maximum permitted

Tags: fpdf, php, email-headers

I'm Beau from [Fijura Web Design](http://www.fijurawebdesign.com.au/) in Perth, Western Australia.

Having an issue on my server. I am trying to create a script that will send an email with an attachment and whenever I try to run the script I get the following response:

> **Warning:** mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 552 5.7.0 DATA
>   header size exceeds maximum permitted in **E:\folder\folder\_api\sendreports.php**
>   on line **52**

The code I am using is a proven script as I use it on shared Linux servers at our data centre but I cannot get it to work on my Windows server. The script I use is:

```
    include "../reports/rankings.php"; //this is my FPDF attachment
    $to=$array['email']; //this pulls an email address from an array output by my MySQL Server
    $from="Fijura SEO<seo@fijura.com.au>";
    $subject="SEO Ranking Report - New Data ".date("d M Y");
    $message="New SEO data is available. See attached report.";

// a random hash will be necessary to send mixed content
    $separator = md5(time());

// carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)
    $eol = PHP_EOL;

// attachment name
    $filename = "SEO-Ranking-Report-".date("d-M-Y").".pdf";

// encode data (puts attachment in proper format)
    $pdfdoc = $pdf->Output("", "S");
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode($pdfdoc));

// main header (multipart mandatory)
    $headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; //If I remove all $header information from this line down the email sends fine, just without the attachment.
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"".$eol.$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;
    $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.".$eol.$eol;

// message
    $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= $message.$eol.$eol;

// attachment
    $headers .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= $attachment.$eol.$eol;
    $headers .= "--".$separator."--";

// send message
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) or die("Failed");
```

The attached PDF should look like this: [Sample SEO Rankings Report](http://www.fijurawebdesign.com.au/docs/Sample-SEO-Rankings-Report.pdf)

also the php.ini file is configured as follows:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.bigpond.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your email will be come back.I have 3 recommendation:
1. Read careful [The Spamhaus Project](http://www.spamhaus.org/) that it cause your emails aren't spam.
2. create an *.eml and send it via socket. your .eml contain of your email such as type of header,body, attachment and etc.
3. don't use mail() function of php language, because some of shared hosting ban it.

Comment: 1. Spamhaus Project is currently irrelevant to my issue, as the email wont sent in the first place, aswell as emails will only be sent to people who are expecting them, therefore not spam.
2. how do I create *.eml, attach a *.pdf and send via socket using php?
3. mail() in php works fine on all shared servers we use and our Linux servers, but we are having issues on our Windows server and ONLY when we add an attachment as described above.

Comment: Also the code is _proven_ to work from other servers, its just this one windows server that it wont work!

Comment: Also the email cannot _come back_ as you say considering it wont send in the first place. At this stage while I am testing the script I am just trying to send it to one of my email addresses.